# Powershell Script - Download SharePoint files from a folder and any subfolders

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, scripting

I'm trying to create a PowerShell script which will download files from a specific folder I have in a SharePoint site. This part seems to be working at moment using the script below.

However, within the SharePoint folder it's downloading files from, there are also some subfolders. And I want the script to also download any files contained within these subfolders as well. But can't seem to get this to work.

Current script:

```
# Site collection URL
$SiteURL = "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/WinTest"

# Connect to SharePoint Online with AppId and AppSecret
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

$LibraryRelativeURL = "/Shared Documents/TEST" # Relative Path of the Library
$DownloadPath = "C:\Users\User1\Downloads\TestFolder"         # Local directory to save downloaded files

# Get all files in the "AUNZ_LIVE" directory
$files = Get-PnPFolderItem -FolderSiteRelativeUrl $LibraryRelativeURL -ItemType File

# Loop through each file and download it
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $FileRelativeURL = $file.ServerRelativeUrl
    $FileName = $file.Name
    $LocalFilePath = Join-Path $DownloadPath $FileName

    Write-Host "Downloading file: $FileName"
    Get-PnPFile -Url $FileRelativeURL -Path $DownloadPath -FileName $FileName -AsFile -Force
}

Write-Host "All files downloaded successfully!"
```

Comment: You can use Recursive with following to get list of files and then download each file one at a time  : https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPFolderItem.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the script I created for downloading all the files from all folders in all document libraries can help you figure it out.

Using the -recursive option on Get-PnPFolderItem didn't work out for me,so I created a recursive function (ProcessFolderRecursive) to first read all the folders starting at the root, and then move down from there.

https://dev.azure.com/nielsziegler/_git/NZ-Scripts?path=/Powershell/O365/SharePoint/DownloadAllFilesToDisk.ps1